# Order of element and cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Quoting: "Suppose that G is a finite group with an element p of order 5 and an element h of order 7. Why must |G| ≥ 35? "

element p of order 5 => does this implies or means that p (a) "is part of" or (b) "is" a cyclic group P such that P={p,p^2,p^3,p^4,p^5=1}?

Comment: You get two subgroups of $G$ : one by taking the cyclic subgroup generated by the order $5$ element (by def'n, this has $5$ elements), and the other by taking the order $7$ element and doing the same thing. Now, by Lagrange's theorem, if $|G|$ is the order of the group, then $5 \ | \ \ |G|$ and $7 \ | \ \ |G|$. Since $5,7$ are relatively co-prime, it follows that $35 | |G|$. Since $|G| \neq 0$, it follows that $|G| \geq 35$. The interesting question : does there exist an element of order $35$ in $G$?

Comment: I think you have got the idea, even though it may need polishing. Nevertheless, I think Lagrange's theorem (once you know it), gives a nicer proof. You should try the interesting question too.

Comment: i was thinking about this: Given P the cyclic subgroup of G of order 5. If [G:P]  is the partition corresponding to the disjoint union of left coset",  |P| has to divide evenly |G|. and similarly, if H is the cyclic group subgroup of G of order 7, then |H| has to divide evenly |G|.

As 35 is the lowest common multiple of 5 and 7, if |G| < 35, then either P or H won't be able to partition evenly G. ; if |G| = 35, then both P and H do partition evenly G if |G| > A and that A ={common multiples of 5 and 7} then H and H do partition G.

Comment: Yes I wanted to get something a little more fluid

Comment: That's much neater, I think, than the previous attempt. Yes, I get the point, it's a counting argument, using the fact that $35$ is the LCM of the quantities.

Answer (score 1):

$g$ has order $5$ means that $g^5=id$ and for all $k\in\{1,2,\ldots\},k<5\Rightarrow g^k\neq id$. This implies that the subgroup generated by $g$ is isomorphic to $C_5$.

The reason why the statement about order $35$ is true is that since there exists an element of order $5$ and an element of order $7$, by Lagrange's Theorem both $5$ and $7$ divide $|G|$ and so $35$ divides $|G|$ since $gcd(5,7)=1$.

Comment: I believe that you are using the fact that $5$ does not divide $7-1=6$ to deduce that if there is an element of order $5$ and an element of order $7$ then there is an element of order $35$. This is not true in general since $S_3$ contains an element of order $2$ and element of order $3$ but not an element of order $6$. However in order to get that $|G|\leq 35$ it is enough to use Lagrange's Theorem to deduce that $5\mid |G|$ and $7\mid |G|$ which implies that $35$ divides $|G|$. Am I right?

Comment: @Levent You're right, I was confusing the Lagrange's theorem approach to looking at the lcm's of the orders. Lagrange is the way to approach this and I have edited by answer accordingly.

Comment: @Levent It also does not work for elements of order $5$ and $7$ as can be seen in $S_7$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yeah, the correct statement is that the order of $ab$ divides the lcm of the orders of $a$ and $b$, not is equal to it.

Comment: No, the order of a product is practically unrelated to the orders of the elements.

Comment: The order of $ab$ divides the lcm when $a$ and $b$ commute. It is not true in general. For example in $S_3$ the product $(12)(13)$ has order $3$.

Comment: Clearly I need to go refresh on group theory!